# Show array increment one by one elements upon onclick function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to print array elements one by one upon onclick. Here's the code through which i am achieving it. The problem with the code, upon first click it does not increment value while it suppose to replace old array element with new +1 element of array.

```js
       function myFunction() {
     var i = 0;
    i++;
        var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits[i];
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> 
     <p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are always setting the `i` variable with 0. Put that variable out of the `myFunction` scope and it will work.

```js
var i = 0;
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
function myFunction() {  
  if (i >= fruits.length) i = 0;
   
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits[i];
  i++;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
</script>
```

But don't forget you can also have the array and the element selector removed out of the scope of the function, making it simpler (and possible faster). Also, check if you'll not exceed the boundaries of the array before incrementing `i` again.

Comment: You are incrementing i before even accessing first value of the array.

Comment: Good one. Fixed.

Comment: You suggest to remove `i` from the scope in order to allow it to increment, which is a solution. However, why then also require a new array to be created each time the function is called? Why require a dom query each time? Oh, and also, why not ensure that the array doesn't go out of bounds using mod? Just, you know, kinda curious.

Comment: I adressed the problem directly, not trying to rewrite the original code (as it may have been simplified for posting). Anyway, I added a comment about other possible changes and improvements.

Comment: @TravisJ I think author wanted to know the exact answer. And adding extras would be a mess for him if he can't understand the scope *imho

Comment: One thing I want to know is why the code produces undefined at last ? and how can we remove it ?

Comment: The undefined is caused because the variable `i` is exceeding the array `fruits` length. I added a check for that condition, when the `i` variable is set to 0 again, so the first item of the array is shown again.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code with looping functionality.

```js
var i = 0;
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
function myFunction() {  
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits[i];
  i++;
  if(i == fruits.length){i = 0;}
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```